# How to get the number of items in a list within an object

Tags: perl, soap

I am a beginner in Perl, I need to get the size of an array

SOAP consultation code is as follows

```
my @params = (
    SOAP::Data->name(user => '2355'),
    SOAP::Data->name(psw  => '2355')
);

my $soap = SOAP::Lite
    ->uri( 'https://service.example.com' )
    ->on_action( sub { join '/', 'https://service.example.com', $_[1] } )
    ->proxy( 'https://service.example.com/service.php?wsdl' );

my $method = SOAP::Data->name('GetAll')
    ->attr( {xmlns => 'https://service.example.com'} );

my @products =  $soap->call($method => @params)->result;
```

This returns

```
$VAR1 = bless({
  date_end => [0, 0, "2016-06-30"],
  dispach => [0, 51, 0],
  manufacturer => ["Microsoft", "Lenovo", "HP"],
  sku => [
    "R23649C          ",
    "DW47-03           ",
    "YDG-016           ",
  ],
  tree => [
    "MS-OPEN             ",
    "LENOVO-AIO          ",
    "HP ACADEMIC   ",
  ],
}, "parametros_salida");
```

I can access the data with

```
print $products->{"sku"}[0];
print $products->{"manufacturer"}[0];
print $products->{"manufacturer"}[1];
```

But I cannot count as the result of my call SOAP only return a single variable Dumper($products) therefore I can not get the array size.

I've tried

```
my @products2 = $products
print 0 + @products2;
print scalar(@products2);
print scalar $products;
```

Comment: You shouldn't be poking around in the internals of objects (things that have been `bless`ed). Instead, you should use the object's methods to access the data that it wants to make public. Can you please edit the full output into your question so we can see what type of object that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***EDIT*** *As others have pointed out, for this specific example - when your hash reference is in fact a blessed reference (that is to say, an object), you should be using the class's API to obtain its members, not digging into the internals of the objects.*
>
> *What follows is a generic answer that explains how to access an equivalent* **unblessed** *Perl data structure, and isn't directly relevant to your situation*

---

`$products` and `@products` are two entirely unrelated variables. They have
nothing to do with one another.

Assuming that `$products` is the variable that you passed to `Data::Dumper` to obtain that output, then `$products` is a reference to a hash.  It is not an array, so I'm not sure what you mean when you ask for the "array size".

You can find out how many keys are in the hash that `$products` references by using:

```
my $key_count = keys %{$products}
```

Or if you wanted the size of the one of the arrays inside the hash that `$products` references, such as `manufacturer`, you can do:

```
my $size = @{ $products->{manufacturer} }
```

You can learn more about Perl references and data structures in Perl from the documentation [*Perl references and nested data structures*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) and [*Perl Data Structures Cookbook*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) which is part of every standard Perl distribution

For proper advice on your situation you should read [*Object-Oriented Programming in Perl Tutorial*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html)

Comment: You should put a loud warning that doing this breaks encapsulation; object methods should be used on a blessed thing. Otherwise, if the author changes any internals, code will break.

Comment: my result es the dumper of $products

Comment: @nasatome: you've been warned twice that although this is a quick fix and it works, the author of the module(s) you're using could change their code, and all of your code may very well break, causing a lot of confusion and wasted time. You're better off spending some time to see if the module's in use have object methods that will do what you want. It could save a lot of time refactoring things later.

Comment: @nasatome: This is **not** a good answer to your question. Unfortunately we can't provide a proper answer without seeing the code or documentation of the `parametros_salida` class. Please don't use this solution just because it "works". Instead you should ask another question giving details of your module's API